# Can we make a "tips and tricks for patent applications" question?

Tags: feature-request

I feel like this would help many people, but it isn't exactly a question answer thing, more like a wiki thing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't we, in principle at least, get this through questions already?

Comment: Yes, but they might be hard to find. A tag maybe?